# LINQ: Using INNER JOIN, Group and SUM and HAVING

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to convert the following SQL using LINQ in c#

```
enter code here
```

```
SELECT  t2.AccountID, t1.Name, t1.ParentID, SUM(t2.Debit), SUM(t2.Credit) 
FROM t2.INNER JOIN
         t1.ON t2.AccountID = t1.ID
GROUP BY t2.AccountID, t2.Name, t1.ParentID
   HAVING  (t1.ParentID = 22)
```

Comment: Your HAVING should be a WHERE. placed before GROUP BY. (The HAVING clause is intended for aggregate function conditions.)

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication23
{

    class Program
    {
       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Name[] names = null;
            Amount[] amounts = null;

            var results = (from t1 in names.Where(x => x.ParentID == 22)
                           join t2 in amounts on t1.ID equals t2.AccountID
                           select new { t1 = t1, t2 = t2 }
                           )
                           .GroupBy(x => new { accountId = x.t2.AccountID, name = x.t1.Name, parent = x.t1.ParentID })
                           .Select(x => new { accountID = x.Key.accountId, name = x.Key.name, parentID = x.Key.parent, debit = x.Sum(y => y.t2.Debit), credit = x.Sum(y => y.t2.Credit) })
                           .ToList();

        }
    }
    public class Name
    {
        public int ParentID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
    public class Amount
    {
        public int AccountID { get; set; }
        public decimal Debit { get; set; }
        public decimal Credit { get; set; }
    }

 
}
```